# What do the following parametric curves represent?

Tags: calculus

(a) $x(v)= 3, y(v)= 4, z(v)= v$ for $−\infty < v < \infty$,

(b) $x(t)= 3\cos(t), y(t)= 2\sin(t), z(t)= 3t−1$ for $0 \leq t < 2\pi$.

I have no idea where to start. Our lecturer in class only went through parametric curves with 2 parameters. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Open GeoGebra 3D (free software which opens in a browser) and in the input line type (3,4,t). Geogebra understands t as a parameter

Comment: Well, (a) is a line perpendicular to $xy$-plane, which intersects the plane in the point $(3,4)$. (b) is a curve like spring with elliptical base (really I don't know its english name)

Comment: In the future, please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and properly format math expressions.

Comment: You don't mean with two *parameters* (which would be a surface) but with three *coordinates*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph of $$x(v)= 3, y(v)= 4, z(v)= v$$ is a vertical line passing through the point $(3,4,0)$ since $x$ and $y$ are fixed and $z$ runs freely from $-\infty $ to $\infty$

The graph of

$$x(t)= 3\cos(t), y(t)= 2\sin(t), z(t)= 3t−1 ,0 \leq t < 2\pi $$ is a spiral curve whose projection on the $x-y$ plane is an ellipse and its $z$ coordinate runs from $-1$ to $6\pi -1$

A three D grapher will help you to visualize the curve in part $b$ better.

Answer (score 0):

Part (a) can be written in the form of $c + mv$, it is a line that passes through point $c$ in the direction of $m$.

In part $b$, the present of sine and cosine suggest rotation as $z$ increases. It is an elliptical helix.

Answer (score 0):

(a) $x(v)= 3, y(v)= 4$ describes a single point, whatever the value of $v$. Then as $z=v$, you get a straight line parallel to the $z$ axis.

(b) $x(t)= 3\cos(t), y(t)= 2\sin(t)$ is an ellipse. Then $z=3t-1$, an affine function of $t$, translates the points parallelly to $z$. You get a single turn of an elliptic helix.

You can as well consider the $xz$ or $yz$ projections, which are sinusoids.